# How does vtk use point cloud clustering algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, cluster-analysis, vtk, point-clouds

I would like to be able to cluster point clouds in C#, unfortunately, PCL does not support C#. I know that C# can use VTK, so I wonder if it is possible to cluster point clouds with VTK, but I don't know if it is possible. Hope someone can give me some advice. Thanks in advance!

I've tried using Euclidean clustering in VTK, but it doesn't work very well. I hope to combine C# and VTK to realize the region growing algorithm, or other point cloud segmentation algorithms, as long as it can be used by C#

Answer (score 0):

To use VTKs [vtkEuclideanClusterExtraction](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkEuclideanClusterExtraction.html#aa2c2575725aee16952c2f3af8a3289a1) is actually not a bad idea.

For the algorithm to work well, you need to make sure that your Point Cloud is clean, so not a lot of outlier points. For this task you can use the `vtkStatisticalOutlierRemoval` for example.

Here is an example on how to use the algorithms (c++):

```
vtkNew<vtkSimplePointsReader> readPointCloud;

readPointCloud->SetFileName(inputWest4.c_str());
readPointCloud->Update();

//Clean PointCloud 
vtkNew<vtkStatisticalOutlierRemoval> removal;
removal->SetInputConnection(readPointCloud->GetOutputPort());
removal->SetSampleSize(5);
removal->SetStandardDeviationFactor(1.0);
removal->Update();

// Cluster Extraction
vtkNew<vtkEuclideanClusterExtraction> cluster;
cluster->SetInputConnection(removal->GetOutputPort());
cluster->SetExtractionModeToAllClusters();
cluster->SetRadius(1.1);
//cluster->ColorClustersOn();
cluster->Update();

cout << "Number of Extracteed Clusters: " << cluster->GetNumberOfExtractedClusters() << endl;
```

Note: With `cluster->SetExtractionModeToAllClusters()` I made sure to extract all the clusters that could be found in the Point Cloud. With `cluster->SetExtractionModeToLargestCluster()` I could just extract the largest Cluster for example.

Output:

cout --> **14**

[Clusters colorized in Blue and red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqFaG.png)

Comment: thanks!It is very helpful to me.I still have a problem，If I want to get the specified point cloud cluster, what should I do?
The vtk does not seem to provide a method to obtain point cloud clusters by index

Comment: with `cluster->GetOutputPort(index)` you can acsess the point cloud cluster by index :)